# Localizing and Globalization of WinForms applications

Tags: winforms, internationalization, globalization, nlp

We've developed a WinForms application (targeting .NET 2.0 with VS2008), we've just found out that we need to localize it for use in another language (other than english) :( What are the guidelines for developing multi-lingual languages in .NET?

Another application borrows Paint.NET's idea of globalization (using resources) but I was wondering if there are tools out there than can automate this for us - free would be nice but commercial is OK too.

Any ideas?

How do people normally work on projects that require multi-lingual interfaces? We're talking WiNForms apps. Do you just use IsLocalized = true and let .NET handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You should create assemblies for each language. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx) article is a good point to start from.

To automate localization process you could use 3rd-party tools, like [ResX Localization Studio](http://resx-localization-studio.net/).